# Integer linear combination of three coprimes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $h, k, l$ be three co-prime integers. Can we always find a set of integers $n_1, n_2, n_3$ such that $n_1 h + n_2 k + n_3 l = 1$ ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to show this for $2$ coprime integers?  Have you tried just extending that argument?

Comment: @Ahmad  I assume (but am not sure) that the OP means that the three numbers are jointly coprime.  That is, that there is no $d>1$ which divides each of the three.  They need not be pairwise coprime.

Comment: @lulu Yes. They need not be pariwise coprimes.